# Remove Second Row From Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to remove the second row of my table with jquery.

I have tried:

```
$("tr:second").remove();
```

But this unfortunately doesnt work :( Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use

```
$("tr:eq(1)").remove();
```

It's zero based, so index 1 is your second row

Comment: @Andrej: If this answer helped you, you should accept it by clicking on the tick outline next to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

use [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector

```
$("table tr:nth-child(2)").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr:eq(1)").remove();
```

second row has number 1

Answer (score 0):

try `$("tr:nth-child(1)").remove()`
http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ':eq()' selector to achieve this:

```
// The eq() selector is zero based so the second
// row will be tr:eq(1)
$("tr:eq(1)").remove();
```

See the documentation at:

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/